# How to iterate through multiple object's and it's properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

So currently I'm creating a website for learning purposes. I'm using [SimpleCart](http://simplecartjs.org/)
for storing the items the user wants to purchase into localStorage. However, now I want to move the data off of localStorage and into my database. Currently I'm using Node.js to handle this. Here is a sample of the code I'm using to add it to my database.

```
function addToDBFood()
{
    var OrderArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("simpleCart_items"));

    var orderDetail = new Object();

    for (var id in OrderArray) {
        if (OrderArray.hasOwnProperty(id)) 
        {
            orderDetail.order_id = OrderArray.id;
            orderDetail.order_item = OrderArray.name;
            orderDetail.order_item_price = OrderArray.price;
            orderDetail.order_quantity = OrderArray.quantity ;

            var addToDB = new XMLHttpRequest();

            addToDB.open("POST", '/orderdetail', true);

            addToDB.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            addToDB.send(JSON.stringify(orderDetail));
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the problem I'm facing is that I cannot get the property of each individual object, for example, if I `console.log(OrderArray.id)` I get undefined. The loop works, as far as I can tell because if I placed the `console.log` in the loop, it will loop for however many objects I have inside localStorage and return that number of undefined in the console. My question is, how do I go about getting the the value of the property of each and every object?

**EDIT:** If I were to run `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("simpleCart_items"))` it returns the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ENyp.png).

Comment: please share the object

Comment: Re the edit: Post textual things (code, JSON, markup, etc.) as **text**, not as *pictures* of text. More: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderArray.id` is looking for an `id` property on `OrderArray`, but your code appears to assume `OrderArray` is a *container* of some kind (probably an array, from the name). So you want to get the `id` property from each *entry* in `OrderArray`.

Without assuming it's an array (just in case), minimal changes to that code would be to do this to fill in `orderDetail`:

```
var entry = OrderArray[id];                  // <== Get this specific entry
orderDetail.order_id = entry.id;             // <== Use the entry
orderDetail.order_item = entry.name;         // ""
orderDetail.order_item_price = entry.price;  // ""
orderDetail.order_quantity = entry.quantity; // ""
```

---

There are other changes I'd make to that code:

1. If `OrderArray` is an array, `for-in` is not a good way to loop through it; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for lots of options for looping through arrays.
2. Even though it will work in your specific case, I wouldn't create a single object (assigned to `orderDetail`) and overwrite its properties in each loop. I'd create separate objects.
3. Obviously you can use any naming conventions in your own code you like, but I would strongly recommend not naming local variables with an initial capital (typically reserved for constructor functions). So `orderArray` rather than `OrderArray`.

So perhaps:

```
function addToDBFood() {
    var orderArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("simpleCart_items"));
    orderArray.forEach(function(entry) {
        var orderDetail = {
            order_id: orderArray.id,
            order_item: orderArray.name,
            order_item_price: orderArray.price,
            order_quantity: orderArray.quantity
        };
        var addToDB = new XMLHttpRequest();
        addToDB.open("POST", '/orderdetail', true);
        addToDB.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        addToDB.send(JSON.stringify(orderDetail));
    });
}
```

...in an ES5 environment. In an ES2015+ environment, largely the same:

```
function addToDBFood() {
    const orderArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("simpleCart_items"));
    for (const entry of orderArray) {
        const orderDetail = {
            order_id: orderArray.id,
            order_item: orderArray.name,
            order_item_price: orderArray.price,
            order_quantity: orderArray.quantity
        };
        const addToDB = new XMLHttpRequest();
        addToDB.open("POST", '/orderdetail', true);
        addToDB.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        addToDB.send(JSON.stringify(orderDetail));
    }
}
```